# Firejail Blacklist/Whitelist Priorities

Tags: whitelist, blacklist, firejail

I have defined the following:

```
whitelist /home/user/.mozilla/firefox/
noblacklist /home/user/.mozilla/firefox/
blacklist /home
```

However I get:
ls: cannot access '/home/user/.mozilla/firefox': Permission denied

If I try

```
blacklist /home
whitelist /home/user/.mozilla/firefox/
```

I get the same message: permission denied.

A similar issue occurs with the /etc folder.
The entire /etc folder is accessible under the jail.
And yes I am aware of the '**--private-etc**' option, but this is not what I am testing right now ...

If I try to whitelist just one folder, I get:

```
Error: invalid whitelist path /etc/subfolder
Error: cannot establish communication with the parent, exiting...
```

I can succesfully blacklist for example /etc/subfolder.
If I try ls -lA /etc/subfolder, I get:

```
ls: cannot open directory '/etc/bind': Permission denied
```

However, when I try "**ls -lA /etc**/", /etc/bind is still listed in the output.
Also, I don't seem to be able to blacklist the entire /etc folder and then whitelist some subfolders within /etc.

With firejail, how can I restrict access to a folder but allow access to selected subforders, i.e :

- restrict access to /home except the ~/.mozilla/firefox subfolder?
- restrict access to /etc except the /etc/abc subfolder?

By "restrict access", I mean all non-whitelisted folders and files being made "invisible" within the jail.

Comment: How have you restricted your access to `/home`? What permissions do you need for `~/.Mozilla/firefox/`?

Comment: You can use `chmod` to change read, write permissions for user, group or others.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a permission problem.
It seems that firejail handles blacklists automatically as soon as a single whitelist statement is issued.

For example:
If I don't issue any blacklist/whitelist, then all the /home/user folder is accessible in the jail.
If I whitelist /home/user/subfolder, then all subfolders in /home/user except ~/.bashrc, ~/.config, ~/subfolder and .Xauthority are automatically blacklisted.
This behavior was certainly not obvious from the man page.

In addition:
If I whitelist /home/abc, then /home/abc is still not accessible in the jail.
Only If I mount bind /home/abc within /home/user, it becomes accessible under the jail.
So any /home folder outside /home/user seems inaccessible even when whitelisted.
Again it is not very clear why firejail doesn't allow overriding the default blacklists.